# Application start up code design

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

We have a class and method for application start up.
Initially it had very less code.

Over the course of time this method was highly abused and everyone started putting their requirements/domain specific requirement into the method. Lot of code and delegated methods which would execute were added to this method.

I think this method method must only execute application start up lifecycle code  any common code which is required by the application like (creation of db, starting of logging etc. ) not any domain/requirement specific code .

Couple of ways i can think of is:

**Observer pattern/event based/OSGI extension point like model:** Application startup event is fired by this application method. All domain specific listeners must execute their code. But here the ordering and dependencies between the listeners code is important.

**Delegated methods to domain specific code** Again this one would increase lot of direct calling of domain specific code sequentially (maintains the order) from the startup code (which is kind of happening in my code )

Would like to know if there is any other way i can solve this design problem ?

cheers,

Saurav

Comment: It sounds like you're lacking an [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container to inject domain-specific dependencies and mange their lifecycles.

Comment: well for us initially to have an IoC container was difficult to have...now since the application have increased into leaps and bounds probably i can think of some IoC container...

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, those two, would be the one I would explore.

On the first case, you could create a tree like structure to represent the dependencies between `Tasks` or `Commands` that are listening for a particular other to finish, and could execute them in parallel etc.

On the second one an approach I've used in medium/big applications was to have different modules that were able to initialise themselves when called from the main application logic. i.e. the bootstrapping code defined them in order or specifying dependencies between them and then delegated the logic of initialising to each Module class.

Other aspects to consider would be:

- How easy is to test the initialisation process works as expected?
- How easy is to follow what is happening in the code?

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs...so you mean that there must be order for execution of listeners for a startup like event must be defined ?

Comment: No, what I tried to say is if you need things to be done in a certain order, then steer your design so that the intention and order is very clear and that it is easy to add a new task in the future

Answer (score 1):

I would begin using an interface to model the application lifecycle you are talking about:

```
interface IApplicationLifecycle
{
    void Startup();
    void Shutdown();
}
```

The next piece would be to refactor all of the lifecycle code into the appropriate module/subsystems implementing that interface. Then have your setup method call into the modules as appropriate.

```
// populate LifecycleCollection (could maintain order there if needed)
public void Start()
{
    foreach (IApplicationLifecycle al in LifecycleCollection)
    {
       al.Startup();
    }
}
```

You are calling into other code so there are going to be dependencies. However, you could standardize the dependency with an interface. Add a configuration file that lists initialize classes, in order, and your startup method would remain unchanged for any given number of changes in the dependent code. I think that is what you should be aiming for here.